# Correct design to pass generics in messages to event listeners

Tags: c++, generics, event-handling, message-passing

Please feel free to truncate this question if it is overly long.

I'm having some trouble understanding how to pass generic arguments to event listeners (e.g. callback functions) without breaking principles of OOP and polymorphism.

For the purposes of this question, assume the implementation is written in C++.

Let's say I have an `animal` class with two children, `cat` and `dog.`

I also have a `doorbell` event object which should cause `dogs` to `speak()`, but `cats` do not respond.

However, I have all of my `animals` stored polymorphically. I cannot simply call `speak()` on every animal, since cats should not respond.

One (bad) solution is to use dynamic casting to check each animal, and see if it's of type `dog.` If so, I call its `speak` function. If not, I don't. The issue here is that it breaks the purpose of polymorphism and virtual functions (not needing to know information about the children classes, but rather just the parent interface).

For a better solution, I might choose to use an event driven system. I'd have an `event_manager,` and each dog is registered as a listener to the `doorbell` event (possibly by some event ID, the event name, etc.) Perhaps each dog registers its callback function with the event.

Then, when the `doorbell` is rung, it tells the `event_manager` to invoke the callback functions of every listener registered to the `doorbell` event.

This is much better, but what if information about the target (the `doorbell_ring`) needs to be passed to the dogs?  For example, how loud did it ring? If it was quiet, perhaps the `dogs` do not respond, based on their hearing capability. Perhaps if it is very loud, the `dogs` respond more aggressively.

The only solution is to pass the target `doorbell` into the event handler (`dog`) callback function.

Here is where I'm confused: every callback function must match the same function signature in order for it to be generically invokeable by the `event_manager`. While in this case the `dogs` need access to the information about the `doorbell_ring,` given any other event, the listener may need access to information about an entirely different target.

The only solution I can think of is passing the targets as `void pointers` and explicitly downcasting to the determined target type (e.g. the dogs, in this callback function, would downcast the target to the `doorbell_ring*` type).

While this would certainly work, isn't it essentially the same as the very first solution, wherein we check if an animal is of type `dog` via dynamic casting and, if so, invoke its response? Imagine that, instead of using dynamic casting, we give every animal a type identifier, and just check against each animals identifier. Now, we're simply casting an animal to a dog based on its identifier. In the event driven system, we're simply casting a target to the determined subtype based on the identifier of the event which invoked the callback.

In a round about way, doesn't this have the same design issues? We're simply using void pointer generics and downcasting to the correct type based on some type id instead of downcasting from the `animal` class to the `dog` class.

Is there a better design pattern?

Comment: Let factory design pattern handle the animals. For dogs, associate with a particular type(s) of events and for cats, other different types.

Comment: @seccpur That doesn't answer my confusion. My confusion is that the polymorphism surrounding events is broken; If `dogs` listen to one type of event, and `cats` another, then you'll have some sort of `register_event(event)` method and `invoke_callbacks(int event_id)` method in the `event_manager`, yet the only thing allowing a listener to distinguish one event type from the next is through the event's `id.` From everything I've read, distinguishing the concrete type of a polymorphic datum, even through an ID rather than dynamic casting, defeats the purpose of polymorphism.